# Using 3D objects with MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, 3d, xamarin.ios

How can I use 3D objects like `md2` with MonoTouch?  I know Unity3D can do that, but it is commercial and not cheap for just using `md2` objects.  Is there any freeware or cheaper library for 3D support?

Answer (score 0):

MonoTouch has no built in support for parsing MD2 objects.  It does have support for OpenGL however, so you could parse the object format yourself and build your own parser / leverage an existing one to get the information from the MD2 to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if there is a immediately-usable monotouch-based md2 project or codebase, however, with the help of http://www.google.com/codesearch, I came across various C#-based md2-handling code fragments, maybe you could adapt any of:

- [vcmdlnet.googlecode.com](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#psb6XQD8nnE/trunk/PluginMd2/Plugin.cs&q=vcmdlnet%20md2&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)
- [jawws.googlecode.com](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#sxmoiRM-JQc/trunk/OpenArtemisProject/OpenArtemisProject/MD2Obj.cs&q=lang%3ac%23%20md2%20-hash%20-cryptography%20-crypto%20-digest%20-database%20-sql&d=3)
- [opimmframework.svn.codeplex.com](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ucQxXapJUlc/Current/Opimm/Opimm/Graphics/Models/MD2MeshLoader.cs&q=lang%3ac%23%20md2%20-hash%20-cryptography%20-crypto%20-digest%20-database%20-sql&sa=N&cd=62&ct=rc)
- [Halolz m2d (XNA[touch?])](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#5ld9_Ra1oWk/trunk/ITP380Final/MD2.cs&q=lang%3ac%23%20md2&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc)

Also, [CSat](http://code.google.com/p/csat) and [Meshomatic](http://www.opentk.com/project/Meshomatic) are C# libraries for loading other model formats, such as Wavefront's Obj format. However, these might require a little work also to port to Monotouch.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Rich

Comment: All the links are dead now that google shut down codesearch :(

Comment: @JesperLarsen-Ledet - Yeh, you're not wrong about the links, shouldn't take too much effort to re-Google the project names though, then point at them directly. I'll update them, soon.